# Spring Security builds fails in CLI and INtelliJ

Tags: spring, gradle

On

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

get below issue:

Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileJava'.

```
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':buildSrc:compileClasspath'.
    Could not resolve io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.5.0-M6.
     Required by:
         project :buildSrc
       Could not resolve io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.5.0-M6.
          Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/projectreactor/reactor-core/3.5.0-M6/reactor-core-3.5.0-M6.pom'.
             Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/projectreactor/reactor-core/3.5.0-M6/reactor-core-3.5.0-M6.pom'. Received status code 401 from server:
```

And in INtelliJ get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD47b.png)

Need help here

1. ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal

Expected successful build

2. Opened project in IntelliJ
   expected project to build and index properly.

Gradle build file:

Details of Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.javaformat:spring-javaformat-gradle-plugin:$springJavaformatVersion"
        classpath 'io.spring.nohttp:nohttp-gradle:0.0.10'
        classpath "io.freefair.gradle:aspectj-plugin:6.6-rc1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "com.netflix.nebula:nebula-project-plugin:8.2.0"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release-local' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
}
```

Comment: We are lacking details, but it looks like you are using a milestone (= old alpha or beta pre-release) of a Spring version that is now released for months. Maybe the `.M6` milestone doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: have added more details . Could you check please